# Getting error: package org.docx4j does not exist during ANT build

Tags: java-8, docx4j

I upgraded my project to **Java 8(jdk1.8.0_191)** and when i tried to build my project using ANT **"apache-ant-1.10.5"** it throws the below error,

```
 [javac] java:43: error: package org.docx4j does not exist
[javac] import org.docx4j.TraversalUtil;
[javac]                  ^
[javac] Servlet.java:44: error: package org.docx4j.TraversalUtil does not exist
[javac] import org.docx4j.TraversalUtil.CallbackImpl;
[javac]                                ^
[javac] Servlet.java:45: error: package org.docx4j.dml does not exist
[javac] import org.docx4j.dml.CTBlip;
[javac]                      ^
[javac] Servlet.java:46: error: package org.docx4j.dml does not exist
[javac] import org.docx4j.dml.CTBlipFillProperties;
[javac]                      ^
[javac] Servlet.java:47: error: package org.docx4j.openpackaging.io does not exist
[javac] import org.docx4j.openpackaging.io.SaveToZipFile;
[javac]
```

and so on.

Im using **docx4j-3.3.7.jar**  . Please save my life to resolve this issue.

With Regards,

Saranya C

Comment: Ensure you really have your docx4j jar on ant's build path.  You should also upgrade to docx4j 8.1.x

Comment: @JasonPlutext: I downloaded the latest "docx4j-core-8.1.0.jar" and added in my build.xml and build path and executed. Still the same error.

Comment: BUILD.xml: <include if="needsdocx4jCore" name="docx4j-core-8.1.0.jar" />

Comment: <target name="_docx4j-core" depends="compile">
    <jar jarfile="${jars.dir}/docx4j-core-8.1.0.jar">
     <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
      <include name="docx4j-core**" />
     </fileset>
    </jar>
   </target>

Comment: You'll also need docx4j's deps; for example https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/etc/build.xml#L93

Comment: @JasonPlutext: Hi Jason! Thanks.Its working fine now